# About the irreducibility and separability of a polynomial

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory, proof-explanation, extension-field, alternative-proof

Theorem: If the extension $E/F$ is finite and Galois, then $E/F$ is normal and separable.

**Proof:** Let $f(x)\in F[x]$ irreducible with a root $\alpha\in E $ and $\sigma_1(\alpha),\dots,\sigma_r(\alpha)$ the orbit of $\alpha$ under $G(E/F).$

The polynomial $\prod_{i=1}^{r}(x-\sigma_i(\alpha))$ is separable and irreducible in $F[x].$

Therefore $\prod_{i=1}^{r}(x-\sigma_i(\alpha))$ splits over $E.$

Thus $E/F$ is normal and separable.
                                                          ◼︎

Why $\prod_{i=1}^{r}(x-\sigma_i(\alpha))$ is separable and irreducible in $F[x]?$ If we know that it is irreducible, then we just need to see that every root $\sigma_i(\alpha)$ is different, i.e. $\sigma_i\neq\sigma_j$ for every $i\neq j.$
 How?

Comment: My definitions for E/F normal is: E/F is normal if every irreducible polynomial $p(x)$ with a root in E, splits on E.

Comment: And $E/F$ is separable if the minimal polynomial $m(x)$ of $\alpha$ is separable, i.e. every irreducible term of $m(x)$ is separable, i.e. all the roots of the irreducible terms are different in every splitting field of the irreducible terms.

Comment: Let $G = Aut(E/F)$ and $E^G = \{ \alpha \in E \ \vert \ \forall g \in G, g(\alpha) = \alpha\}$ the fixed field. Then $E/F$ is Galois iff $F = E^G$. In general, for any $\alpha \in E$, the polynomial $\prod_{\beta \in G \alpha} (x-\beta)$ is the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$ over $E^G$ (ie. $E/E^G$ is normal and separable).

Comment: @reuns is there a proof for 'for any $\alpha\in E,$ the polynomial $\prod_{\beta \in G \alpha} (x-\beta)$ is the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$ over $E^G$'?

Comment: Yes : $f(x) = \prod_{\beta \in G \alpha} (x-\beta) = \sum_{n=0}^d a_n x^n \in E[x]$. If $\sigma \in Aut(E/E^G)$ then $\sum_{n=0}^d \sigma(a_n) x^n = \prod_{\beta \in G \alpha} (x-\sigma(\beta))=\prod_{\beta \in \sigma G \alpha} (x-\beta)= f(x)$. Thus $a_n=\sigma(a_n)$ and $a_n \in E^G$ and $f \in E^G[x]$. Irreducibility follows from $f \in E^G[x], f(\alpha) = 0, \alpha \in E,\sigma \in Aut(E/E^G) \implies \sigma(f(\alpha)) =  f(\sigma(\alpha)) = 0$.

Comment: @reuns $G = Aut(E/F)$ is the Galois group ?

Comment: why $f\in E^G[x]?$

Comment: What do you mean ? This is what I explained in my last comment : $G$ is a group of automorphisms of $E$ and $E^G$ is its fixed field, then everything follows nicely.

Comment: @reuns how are related all the $\sigma_i(\alpha)?$ from $\prod_{i=1}^{r}(x-\sigma_i(\alpha))$