# If $\mathbb K:\mathbb F$ is Galois, then it is normal and separable

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory, extension-field, alternative-proof

I'm trying to proof this proposition (below), I already find a proof in a pdf file but it was difficult to understand so I though would be better  to do it myself but I got stuck trying to do it. Please help me, please!

Proposition: If $[\mathbb K:\mathbb F]<\infty$ and it is Galois, then it is normal and separable.

Proof: We need to show that every irreducible $p(x)\in\mathbb F$ with one root $\alpha\in\mathbb K,$ splits over $\mathbb K$. (This is for normality)
**and** that for every $\alpha\in\mathbb K $ is separable.

So let $p(x)\in\mathbb F$ be irreducible with one root $\alpha\in\mathbb K$ and let $\alpha\in\mathbb K. $

By hypothesis, $G(\mathbb K:\mathbb F)^+=\sigma(\mathbb F)≈\mathbb F$ and also we have that $\mathbb K$ is a splitting field of a separable $p(x)\in\mathbb F.$

Now let $\sigma\in G(\mathbb K:\mathbb F)^+$ and consider the polynomial $x-\alpha\in\mathbb K.$ Thus $\sigma(x-\alpha)=x-\sigma(\alpha)$.

So we can get something like this $f(x)=\prod_{\sigma\in G(\mathbb K:\mathbb F)^+}(x-\alpha)=\prod_{\sigma\in G(\mathbb K:\mathbb F)^+}(x-\sigma(\alpha))$.

Now $f(x)\in\mathbb K$ and splits on it too, can I considerer $f$ to be the same irreducible polynomial as $p(x)?.$ If I can consider $f(x)=p(x),$ then $\mathbb K:\mathbb F$ would be normal.

The only thing to show now would be to proof that each $\sigma_i(\alpha)$ is different to then be able to conclude that each root of $f(x)$ it's different on $\mathbb F.$ How can I do this?

Any kind of help would be very appreciated :)

Comment: What definition of $K/F$ Galois are you using?

Comment: @cat :) $K/F$ is Galois if $G(\mathbb K:\mathbb F)^+=\sigma(\mathbb F)$, where $\sigma$ is the monomorphism

Comment: This is a very standard theorem in any textbook on basic algebra.  The proof really depends on how the author has constructed the preliminaries it's hard to prove from scratch without knowing exactly what theorems you have at hand and exactly what definitions you're operating with.  For example I am very familiar with Galois theory but I don't recall seeing that notation before $G(\Bbb K:\Bbb F)^{+}$.  What do you mean $\sigma$ is "the" monomorphism?  There is no canonical monomorphism associated with an extension.

Comment: @GregoryGrant no, it's not a very standard theorem in any textbook on basic algebra (I've searched in many), if it is, please mention the name of the book. Haha yes my professor it's a little bit unusual with his notations, $G(\Bbb K:\Bbb F)^{+}$ it's the fixed Galois group of the extension. And $\sigma$ it's the monomorphism between $\mathbb K$ and $\mathbb F$, i.e. $\sigma:\mathbb F\to\mathbb K$

Comment: What theorems do I have at hand? Almost of the theorems from Herstein's book (Chapter 5: Fields)

Comment: i'm confused by the definition... you're saying that a group $G(\mathbb K/\mathbb F)^+$ equals the image of a field $\sigma(\mathbb F)$ ...

Comment: @cat yes, the fixed group is a subset of $\mathbb K$ and also $\sigma(\mathbb F)$ is a subset of $\mathbb K$

Comment: It is one of the basic theorems in any textbook that covers Galois Theory.  It's one of the absolutely fundamental results.  Every book I have on algebra has it.  Hungerford, Jacobson, Dummit and Foote.  You can't really do Galois theory without it. In Hungerford it's Corllary 3.15 on page 265 the proof is short because of theorems 3.11 and 3.14.  To prove it from scrach requires many pages.

Comment: I think you mean the fixed *field* of the group of automorphisms of $K$ pointwise fixing $F$...

Comment: @GregoryGrant what is the exactly name of the book by Hungerford? algebra? abstract algebra: an introduction?

Comment: @cat yes that's right

Comment: I think the definition you're referring to is $K/F$ is Galois if $K^{Aut(K/F)} = F$, where if $H \leqslant Aut(K)$ is a subgroup then $K^H$ is the fixed field of $H$. As @GregoryGrant said, this is a standard theorem in most abstract algebra texts that cover Galois theory

Comment: Hungerford is just called "Algebra".  I thought it was one of the best written math textbooks I ever read.  But it is not a very light treatment, he does a lot of infinite extension stuff.  But very nicely.

Comment: ok, thank you @GregoryGrant, I have to say it's one of the best (completely) proofs I 've seen.

Comment: What you wrote [there](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2370500/about-the-irreducibility-and-separability-of-a-polynomial?noredirect=1#comment4890797_2370500) is completely uncorrect. Don't delete a question : where the comments give you the answer, in particular if it is to ask it again just after.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a not so uncommon mistake. If $G = \{\sigma_1, \dots, \sigma_n\}$ then $\sigma_1(\alpha), \dots, \sigma_n(\alpha)$ are not all distinct. If they were then the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$ would have $n$ roots: $\sigma_1(\alpha), \dots, \sigma_n(\alpha)$. Consequentially, $[\mathbf{F}(\alpha) : \mathbf{F}]$ would be $n$, which is true for most $\alpha$ but not all $\alpha$.

Define the subgroup $G_\alpha = \{\sigma \in G : \sigma(\alpha) = \alpha\}$, called the stabilizer of $\alpha$. Also define $G\cdot\alpha = \{\sigma(\alpha) : \sigma \in G\}$, called the orbit of $\alpha$. The set $G\cdot\alpha$ consists of the distinct values of $\sigma(\alpha)$ as $\sigma$ runs over all the elements of $G$.

The minimal polynomial of $\alpha$ is

$$ f_\alpha(x) := \prod_{\beta \in G \cdot \alpha} (x - \beta). $$

The polynomial given by

$$ \prod_{\sigma \in G} (x - \sigma(\alpha)) $$

is called the characteristic polynomial of $\alpha$ and is equal to $f_\alpha(x)^{[\mathbf{K} : \mathbf{F}(\alpha)]}$.

#### Why is $f_\alpha$ the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$?

- First, note that $f_\alpha(\alpha) = 0$, which follows since $\alpha = \operatorname{id}(\alpha) \in G \cdot \alpha$.
- Second, note that $f_\alpha \in \mathbf{F}[x]$, which follows since for all $\tau \in G$ we have $$\tau \cdot (G \cdot \alpha) = \{\tau(\beta) : \beta \in G \cdot \alpha\} = \{\tau\sigma(\alpha) : \sigma \in G\} = \{\sigma(\alpha) : \sigma \in G\} = G\cdot \alpha.$$
  Hence,
  $$\tau \cdot f_\alpha(x) = \tau \cdot \prod_{\beta \in G \cdot \alpha} (x - \beta) = \prod_{\beta \in G \cdot \alpha} (x - \tau(\beta)) = \prod_{\gamma \in \tau\cdot(G \cdot \alpha)} (x - \gamma) = \prod_{\gamma \in G \cdot \alpha} (x - \gamma) = f_\alpha(x). $$
  Therefore $f_\alpha(x) \in \mathbf{K}^G[x] = \mathbf{F}[x]$. Here $\mathbf{K}^G$ is the fixed field of $G$ and equals $\mathbf{F}$ since $\mathbf{K}/\mathbf{F}$ is Galois.
- Third note that $f_\alpha$ is minimal. Indeed if $f(\alpha) = 0$ then $f(\sigma(\alpha)) = \sigma(f(\alpha)) = \sigma(0) = 0$ for all $\sigma \in G$. Thus $\sigma(\alpha)$ is a root for all $\sigma \in G$. Thus $f_\alpha \mid f$.

Finally, we note that $f_\alpha$ splits over $\mathbf{K}$ and is separable, by construction.

---

### The proof that $$\prod_{\sigma \in G} (x - \sigma(\alpha)) = f_\alpha(x)^{[\mathbf{K} : \mathbf{F}(\alpha)]}.$$ Only read if interested.

The Galois Correspondence Theorem says:

> There is a one-to-one correspondence between subgroups $H$ of $G$ and subextensions $\mathbf{K}/\mathbf{K'}/\mathbf{F}$ given by $H \mapsto \mathbf{K}^{H}$ (the fixed field of $H$) and $\mathbf{K}' \mapsto \operatorname{Gal}(\mathbf{K}/\mathbf{K}')$.  Moreover, $|H| = [\mathbf{K} : \mathbf{K}^H]$ and $[G : \operatorname{Gal}(\mathbf{K}/\mathbf{K}')] = [\mathbf{K}' : \mathbf{F}]$.

The correspondence theorem tells us that $|G_\alpha| = [\mathbf{K} : \mathbf{K}^{G_\alpha}]$. But we know that $G_\alpha$ is exactly the group that fixed $\alpha$. Thus $G_\alpha$ fixes $\mathbf{F}(\alpha)$, i.e. $$|G_\alpha| = [\mathbf{K} : \mathbf{F}(\alpha)]. \tag{1}$$

Decompose $G$ as a disjoint union of cosets of $G_\alpha$: $$G = \sigma_1G_\alpha \cup \cdots \cup \sigma_rG_\alpha \tag{2}$$
Then $\sigma_1(\alpha), \dots, \sigma_r(\alpha)$ are all distinct because otherwise $\sigma_i(\alpha) = \sigma_j(\alpha)$ implies $\sigma_j^{-1}\sigma_i(\alpha) = \alpha$ implies $\sigma_j^{-1}\sigma_i \in G_\alpha$ implies $\sigma_iG_\alpha = \sigma_jG_\alpha$. Since the cosets are disjoint, this forces $i = j$.

We also know that $\{\sigma_1(\alpha), \dots, \sigma_r(\alpha)\} = G \cdot \alpha$. Certainly $$\{\sigma_1(\alpha), \dots, \sigma_r(\alpha)\} \subseteq \{\sigma(\alpha) : \sigma \in G\} = G \cdot \alpha \tag{3}$$ and if $\sigma \in G$ then we can write $\sigma = \sigma_i\tau$ for some $i \in \{1,\dots,r\}$ and $\tau \in G_\alpha$ by $(2)$ and then $\sigma(\alpha) = \sigma_i(\tau(\alpha)) = \sigma_i(\alpha)$ (note: $\tau(\alpha) = \alpha$ by definition of $G_\alpha$). Thus $$G \cdot \alpha \subseteq \{\sigma_1(\alpha), \dots, \sigma_r(\alpha)\}. \tag{4}$$ Combining $(3)$ and $(4)$ gives us
$$ \{\sigma_1(\alpha), \dots, \sigma_r(\alpha)\} = G \cdot \alpha \tag{5}. $$

Therefore
\begin{align}
\prod_{\sigma \in G} (x - \sigma(\alpha)) &= \prod_{i = 1}^r \prod_{\tau \in G_\alpha} (x - \sigma_i\tau(\alpha)) \tag{by (2)} \\
&= \prod_{i = 1}^r \prod_{\tau \in G_\alpha} (x - \sigma_i(\alpha)) \tag{def. of $G_\alpha$} \\
&= \left( \prod_{i = 1}^r (x - \sigma_i(\alpha)) \right)^{|G_\alpha|} \\
&= \left( \prod_{\beta \in G \cdot \alpha} (x - \beta) \right)^{|G_\alpha|} \tag{by (5)} \\
&= f_\alpha(x)^{|G_\alpha|} \tag{def. of $f_\alpha(x)$} \\
&= f_\alpha(x)^{[\mathbf{K} : \mathbf{F}(\alpha)]}. \tag{by (1)}
\end{align}

Comment: Why $\alpha = \operatorname{id}(\alpha) \in G \cdot \alpha$ ?

Comment: @Anne $\operatorname{id}$ is the identity function defined by $\operatorname{id}(x) = x$ so $\operatorname{id}(\alpha) = \alpha$. The point of writing $\alpha$ this way is because $G \cdot \alpha$ is the set of anything that looks like "(function in $G$) applied to $\alpha$" so we are taking $\operatorname{id}$ for the function in $G$.

Comment: I see, also I haven't notice but the identity is the only function in G so my question was kinda obvious

Comment: At the beginning,  'if $\sigma_i(\alpha)$ were all different, then $[\mathbf{F}(\alpha) : \mathbf{F}]=n$ which it's true for most $\alpha$ but not all $\alpha$' why it's not true for all $\alpha $? I have a Theorem where it says is true for all $\alpha$

Comment: For example, let $\mathbf{K} = \mathbf{Q}(i)$ and $\mathbf{F} = \mathbf{Q}$ then $n = [\mathbf{Q}(i) : \mathbf{Q}] = 2$ and for $\alpha = 2 + 3i$ we have $[\mathbf{Q}(2 + 3i) : \mathbf{Q}] = 2$. But for $\alpha = 2$ we have $[\mathbf{Q}(2) : \mathbf{Q}] = 1$ since $\mathbf{Q}(2) = \mathbf{Q}$.

Comment: @Anne Your theorem probably says that $[\mathbf{F}(\alpha) : \mathbf{F}] =$ the degree of the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$ over $\mathbf{F}$. But I am using $n = [\mathbf{K} : \mathbf{F}]$.

Comment: yes that's exactly what it says, but in your answer you used $[\mathbf{F}(\alpha) : \mathbf{F}] =n$

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/62946/discussion-between-trevor-gunn-and-anne-t).

Comment: I've another question about this proof, why $f_\alpha(x) = \prod_{\beta \in G \cdot \alpha} (x - \beta)$ has the minimal degree compared to all polynomials in $\mathbf{K}?$. Because I think it's a condition to have the minimal degree among all polynomial in $\mathbf{K}$

Comment: @Anne If a polynomial over $\mathbf{F}$ has $\alpha$ as a root then it has $\sigma(\alpha)$ as a root for each $\sigma \in G$. Thus it must have at least $|G \cdot \alpha|$ roots which is the same as having degree at least $|G \cdot \alpha|$.

Comment: ok, so is that the formal argument to say $f_\alpha$ has minimal degree? I ask you this because I probably going to expose this proof to my teacher, and he usually wants very clear explanations to everything :(

Comment: @Anne Yes, but also see the argument in the third bullet for why $\sigma(\alpha)$ is a root of $f_\alpha$.

Comment: what's the bullet?

Comment: $\sigma(\alpha)$ is a root because $\sigma\in G$ and the functions in G fix elements, so $\sigma(\alpha)=\alpha$

Comment: @Anne Under "Why is $f_α$ the minimal polynomial of $α$?" This is a bullet: $\bullet$

Comment: I see, and my argument it's not correct?

Comment: @Anne Elements of $G$ fix elements of $\mathbf{F}$ but don't fix every element of $\mathbf{K}$ unless $\mathbf{K} = \mathbf{F}$.

Comment: did you assume that $\mathbf F$ is a subset of $\mathbf K$ (in the whole proof)?

Comment: @Anne Yes, that's what I'm taking as the definition of an extension of fields.

Comment: oh, turns out that is not my definition for field extensions :O

Comment: From your own perspective, Is this proof an easy proof?. For an undergraduate student, what do you think is the difficulty level (from 0 to 10)?

Comment: @Anne It's on the easier side meaning that if you understand the concepts of Galois theory well then you could come up with the proof on your own. I think understanding the concepts of Galois theory is difficult because many of the examples are complicated and abstract. The converse (normal and separable -> Galois) is harder.

Comment: yes I think you're right but even in the case were I understand well the theory , I think it might take many hours or more to have the proof (made by myself).

Comment: how did you know that the minimal polynomial $f_\alpha(x)$ had to be that way, i.e.  all it's roots in the orbit of $\alpha$: $G\cdot \alpha?$

Comment: @Anne That's just one of the basic facts one needs to know.

Comment: oops I already asked a question about it

Comment: Sir gunn no one answer my question.. :(